# SVD of product of three matrices

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Are there any library implementation tor numerical routine for SVD of product of three general matrices?
I know the three matrices separately and want to avoid multiplying them directly before SVD. Any simple algorithm will also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you an answer for the case of the product of 2 matrices ?

Comment: There are papers with algorithms for SVD of two and three product-matrices, without explicitly finding the matrix product. For example for [2 matrices](https://www.uv.es/jclaver/papers/1999_Pallel%20Computacion%20of%20the%20SVD%20of%20a%20matrix%20product_PVM_MPI%201999.pdf) and for [3 matrices] (https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0165-1684(91)90062-n). However gal/lapack et. do not have implementations. While writing a code from these papers is certainly possible, I am looking for an optimized library routine.

Comment: Probably disconnected, but a wealth of information in this thesis: https://radimrehurek.com/phd_rehurek.pdf